# POST JSON in multipart/form-data content type (JavaScript)

Tags: json, axios, multipartform-data, content-type

I am trying to send an object within a multipart/form-data request, the problem is that no matter what I do, I get this error: 'Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported'.
It's the same error that I get when I delete the 'application/json' content type from postman. I have tried different solutions that were suggested in similar questions but none of those worked.

This is how it should be configured in postman to work:
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weCDB.png)

And this is the request that returns the error mentioned above:

```
    const data = JSON.stringify(values);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('metadata', data);

    return await axios.post(
        url,
        formData
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, try this:

```
const json = JSON.stringify(values);

const dataTemp = new Blob([json], { 
  type: 'application/json' 
});

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('metadata', dataTemp);
```

Apologize if it does not work.